# Why is my $sce.trustAsHtml content being rendered as plain text?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not sure what I am missing here but for some reason my iFrame is being rendered as text instead of HTML. We are using Angular 1.3.15.

Here is my view:

```
<span ng-bind-html="question.questionLabel"></span>
```

Here is my controller:

```
vm.questionLabel = $sce.trustAsHtml('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3aL9qqWRm7E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

And the following is what is getting rendered to the page in text form:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3aL9qqWRm7E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have injected ngSanitize into the controller as well. I see no errors in the logs. I am at a loss. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't ng-bind-html bind to vm.questionLabel?

Comment: @NexusDuck He probably uses the `QuestionCtrl as question` syntax

Comment: I suppose you are saying you've inject `ngSanitize` into the module?

Comment: please provide more of your view html, and your whole controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **ngSanitize**

Please check this working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/RPOznM12iwVNZjv6MiO8?p=preview

Download file - angular-sanitize.js and include it in your app.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngSanitize"]);       

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.html = '<p>Your html code</p>';
});

<div ng-app="myApp">
     <div ng-controller="myController">
        <p ng-bind-html="html"></p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I incorrectly injected ngSanitize into my controller. It is working now.

Thank you all!

Comment: Great that you found the reason, but better accept [@User2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30612949/1225328) answer by [clicking on the check mark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) beside their answer, since they put you on the right track ([Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110)) `:)`